# How do I share an object between a WCF service and a client?

Tags: .net, wcf, service, remoting

I have three programs in a distributed system that rely on WCF services for communication. If I have a data type used in the WCF service library, how do I access it from the client that has referenced the service?

I am able to instantiate objects defined in the WCF service from the client console application, although there's not much else I can do with it. I can't access any of the object's member methods or fields.

For example, I have this Transaction object class that is used in the service library and client:

```
[DataContract]
public class Transaction
{
    public int checkoutID;
    public DateTime time;
    public List<object> products;
    public double totalPrice;
    public bool complete;

    [OperationBehavior]
    public void Start(int ID)
    {
        checkoutID = ID;
        products = new List<object>();
        complete = false;
    }

    [OperationBehavior]
    public void Complete()
    {
        time = DateTime.Now;
        complete = true;
    }
}
```

This is taken from the interface file for the service (IService) where another class is defined, called CompositeType. What am I missing? I thought WCF services allow remoting of methods and data types?

Thanks to anyone who can help, I've been having problems with WCF for a while.

Comment: I've added a DLL for the service to use which defines the Transaction class, however the service fails to host because it cannot serialise the class. How do I include it for serialising?

Answer (score 8):

WCF is a **message passing** system - all the client and server share is the **service contract** (e.g. the service methods and the structure of the data types used).

What goes over the wire between client and server is basically an XML-serialized representation of your data contract objects. But WCF is by default **not sharing** code - only contracts (e.g. not data types / classes, only their XML representation).

So by default, when a client creates a client proxy for a given service, it will be able to determine the service methods and the XML shape of the data being passed back and forth - and based on that information, it will create client-side data classes that have the exact same XML representation on the wire - but they're different .NET classes (in a client-side namespace).

If you control both ends of the communication - the server and the client - and both are using .NET, you *can* do this:

- put your service and data contracts into a separate assembly (`YourService.Contracts` or something like that)
- let the server-side code reference that assembly and use its interfaces and types
- **before** creating the client-side proxy, add a reference to that shared contracts assembly
- in this case, when you create the client-side proxy (using `Add Service Reference` or the `svcutil` command-line tool), the WCF runtime will detect that it knows about the types needed already (since those are defined in the shared assembly), and it will **reuse those shared types** instead of creating new client-side only data classes.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I have been down this route before. I had the Transaction class in a DLL which the client and service referenced locally, however I could never get the service to work because it kept reporting that the transaction class couldn't be serialised when the service tried to run. If I do this, do I need to declare the Transaction class fields and methods in the service interface file too?

Comment: @Lee: well, first off - `Transaction` is a very bad name - it's used by .NET and T-SQL all over the place. I'd try to use something more meaningful. So maybe your service just picked up the wrong class? The .NET `Transactions` class instead of your own ?

Comment: I understand this, I'll change it. However using the DLLs the client wanted its own namespace.Transaction as did the server. They never agreed on the actual DLL namespace.Transaction, if you see what I'm saying?

Comment: Another problem: you should **not** have any logic (method) in your `[DataContract]` classes - not even if you use the shared assembly approach. Furthermore: if you're using `[DataContract]` on the class - you must also use `[DataMember]` on the fields/properties to serialize them. Are you?? Doesn't look like it from the sample you've posted (but that could be incomplete)

Comment: My debugger gives an error when I don't define bodies for the Transaction class methods since it's not abstract.

Answer (score 0):

I am not able to understand your question completely but from the code pasted above, you are sharing the methods with the WCF client and not the fields/properties. You need to apply [DataMember] attribute in the fields as well.

Comment: I'm tyring to get a client and a service to be able to use an object I've defined as Transaction, which has its own fields and methods.

Answer (score 0):

Add the [DataMember] tag to the fields - they're serialized then.

Also, [OperationContract] should be on the methods, not [OperationBehavior]